# How do I ensure D3 bar plot bars don't move away from their ticks while being responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, visualization

I am trying to create a bar plot in D3 that displays negative and positive values. The code I have does this however I have an issue with the rectangle not sitting correctly on the x-Axis. For example the rectangle for the year 1880 sits a few spaces to the right of the 1880 tick. Also the bar representing 2000 sits around the 1990 mark on the x-Axis. Ideally I want the chart to be able to fill the space of the screen responsively but ensure the bars dont move away from their ticks.

I had assumed that .rangeBoundBands would space it out evenly but it looks like there is something else that's not quite working. Would really appreciate any help that anybody could offer. Code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Land Ocean Temperature Index</title>
        <!-- // <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3.v3.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">

            html, body, * {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 14px 65%;
            }

            .bar.positive {
              fill: darkred;
            }

            .bar.negative {
              fill: steelblue;
            }

            g.infowin {
                fill: grey;
            }

            g.infowin text,
            .axis text {
              font: 11px sans-serif;
              fill:grey;
            }

            .axis path,
            .axis line {
              fill: none;
              stroke: #000;
              shape-rendering: crispEdges;
            }

            path.domain {
                stroke:none;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var margin = {
                top: 10,
                right: 10,
                bottom: 20,
                left: 30
            },
            width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

            var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .2);

            var xAxisScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([1880, 2015])
            .range([0, width]);

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xAxisScale)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickFormat(d3.format("d"));

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

            var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/djr-taureau/d3599e17a3f1c5089a10e26dac9aee03/raw/a43e610d8b1c99bc17b8789b5641b84f243871b1/Land-Ocean-TempIndex-YR.csv", type, function(error, data) {
            x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
                return d.Year;
            }));
            y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
                return d.Celsius;
            })).nice();

            svg.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", function(d) {

                    if (d.Celsius < 0){
                        return "bar negative";
                    } else {
                        return "bar positive";
                    }

                })
                .attr("data-yr", function(d){
                    return d.Year;
                })
                .attr("data-c", function(d){
                    return d.Celsius;
                })
                .attr("title", function(d){
                    return (d.Year + ": " + d.Celsius + " °C")
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {

                    if (d.Celsius > 0){
                        return y(d.Celsius);
                    } else {
                        return y(0);
                    }

                })
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return x(d.Year);
                })
                .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return Math.abs(y(d.Celsius) - y(0));
                })
                .on("mouseover", function(d){
                    // alert("Year: " + d.Year + ": " + d.Celsius + " Celsius");
                    d3.select("#_yr")
                        .text("Year: " + d.Year);
                    d3.select("#degrree")
                        .text(d.Celsius + "°C");
                });

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .append("text")
                .text("°Celsius")
                .attr("transform", "translate(15, 40), rotate(-90)")

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "X axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left - 6.5) + "," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .append("line")
                .attr("y1", y(0))
                .attr("y2", y(0))
                .attr("x2", width);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "infowin")
                .attr("transform", "translate(50, 5)")
                .append("text")
                .attr("id", "_yr");

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "infowin")
                .attr("transform", "translate(110, 5)")
                .append("text")
                .attr("id","degrree");
            });

            function type(d) {
            d.Celsius = +d.Celsius;
            return d;
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make center of a bar right on the tick, subtract its half-width from the bar's `x` coordinate:

```
attr("x", function(d) {
  return x(d.Year) - x.rangeBand() / 2;
})
.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks so much for getting back to me! I did try subtracting the bar's half-width but it still doesnt seem to be sitting right. Strangely the bars for the earlier years are closer to their ticks but then they get progressively further away as you go through the years.

Comment: @PolarW `x` and `xAxisScale` in your code seem to be the same - merge them into a single variable

Comment: Ah thats great point. However, I've merged them both on 'x', the labels still seem to be mis-aligned and also now showing all ticks rather than every ten years. Hopefully you can see what I've done here [https://liveweave.com/3et4b4#&togetherjs=Vu80KMbPQL]